# Yii switching to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, yii

I know, that switching to HTTPS has nothing to do with Yii, and it is mainly adding 
`rewrite rules` in `.htaccess`.
Now I am facing some problems. After I changed my `.htaccess` file 

**from**

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# manual change the url base
RewriteBase /

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

**to**

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.domain.de/$1 [R,L]


# manual change the url base
RewriteBase /

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

The first login page is automatically redirected from `http` to `https` as I wanted, but there are no `css` and images loaded. 
I have noticed that all the paths to these files are `relative`, so `https://my.domain.de/css/print.css` is not found, but 
`http://my.domain.de/css/print.css` is accessible.
 And if I go through the links in web-site `css` and `images` are everywhere missed. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Never-mind, I v just found out the reason. It is just about switching places in `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite conditions only affect the immediately following rule. The two `!-f` and `!-d` conditions need to be applied to the routing rule: `RewriteRule . index.php`. Otherwise, everything blindly gets routed to `index.php` and request for files that actually exist won't get fulfilled.

Additionally, the redirect needs to be **before** the routing rule, so you need to move your conditions to be right above your routing rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

# manual change the url base
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my.domain.de/$1 [R,L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```